# Define custom commands for the * and + registers

Tags: register, os-clipboard, x11, external-command

If I'm using a build of Vim with the [`xterm_clipboard`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+xterm_clipboard) feature then the system [clipboard](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#clipboard) content is available through the `+` register.

If the build I'm using doesn't have this feature, can I make the `"+` register call my custom programs to retrieve and set the system clipboard ([`xsel -bo`](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) and `xsel -bi`, or likewise with [`xclip`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/))? Likewise with `"*` to call `xsel -po` and `xsel -pi`.

The point is to be able to type something like `"+p` without having to worry whether the feature is available. Typing `:r !xsel -b<Enter>` is not what I'm looking for: I want the same keystrokes to work, and I want the paste variants to follow what's available for “true” registers (`P`, `gp`, …).

Bonus: can I define custom commands for other register names?

Comment: See also [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/48490).

Answer (score 8):

A few `<expr>` mapping should be able to do the job here.  The basic structure would be

```
function! ClipboardOrXclip(command, register)
    if a:register !~ '[+*]' || has('xterm_clipboard') || has('gui_running')
        " Just return the original command if the clipboard is accessible
        " or it's not a register that should be handled by xsel
        return a:command
    endif
    if a:register == '+'
        return "<Esc>:r !xsel -bo<CR>"
    else
        return "<Esc>:r !xsel -po<CR>"
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <expr> p ClipboardOrXclip('p', v:register)
```

The function would need to be expanded to handle all the variations of `p`, `P`, `gp`, etc. but this should be a good start.

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, but it isn't working. A plain `p` (without a preceding `"` and register name) doesn't do anything other than make `"p` appears in the status line. `"ap` is equivalent to `a`, `"bp` beeps, … I don't get the logic. `"+` beeps immediately, I don't even get to say that I mean `+` or `*` as a register name.

Comment: Assuming these fundamental problems are solved, is there an exhaustive list of commands I'd need to override? The set looks daunting, especially if I want to support yanking as well.

Comment: @Gilles Updated to fix the behavior with non-+/* registers.  The problem with `"+` when your vim has `-xterm_clipboard` is more difficult because it never gets to this function.  Specifying an invalid register (`+`) aborts the command.  SO, it looks like the behavior actually has to be inverted so map the `"+` or `"*` and then handle the command specified by the user...