# Is there a way to strip the contents of register before pasting

Tags: register, whitespace

There are times I know I just want to paste the content of the register inline where my cursor is, so the initial and trailing whitespace (newline, tab, etc) is not wanted.

Because selecting contents on a web browser does not always reflect what's being copied, I am forced to just clean up after pasting or paste in another line then copy the contents without whitespace to a proper place.

So how can I paste without the whitespace?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076320/remove-whitespace-from-vim-yank-register

You can put `let @t = substitute(@t, '\_s\+', ' ', 'g')` and bind it to a key...

Comment: Related: [Define custom commands for the * and + registers](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/332/51)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to "cast" register contents into a certain (characterwise / linewise / blockwise) mode so often, I wrote the [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) for it. It provides `gcp`, `glp`, etc. alternatives to the built-in paste commands that force a certain mode (and by now several more variations on this theme, like pasting with joined by commas or queried characters).

The `gcp` mapping pastes characterwise (inner newline characters and indent are flattened to a single space, leading and trailing removed).

If you just want to remove leading and trailing whitespace, you can use `g=p` with this expression: `ingo#str#Trim(v:val)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to paste where your cursor is, you could try pasting **in insert** mode with:

```
<C-R>"
```

The command above (- ctrl-r + " - ) will not add a new line.

If you have more than one line of text to paste, and want to get rid any empty space that might come along, you could create a macro:

```
qq
:e testtext
^d0
dG
:bd!
pq
```

This macro ('@q') will open a new buffer called testtext (':e testtext'), go to the first non-empty character on the line ('^') and delete until the beginning of the line ('d0'), close the buffer without saving (':bd!'), and paste the text on the original file without the initial blank spaces.

Just out of curiosity, could you give an example of a real situation? All situation I could think of, could be solved with a macro and/or a mapping. But I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Additional information about the topic:

Many tips on [how to remove unwanted whitespaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces)

A script that [deletes white spaces](https://github.com/vim-scripts/DeleteTrailingWhitespace) at the end of lines.

Comment: @Gregory-Nisbet 's comment seems to be way more interesting (he commented while I was writing, so I'll keep the answer above until the author decides which one helps).