# How to automatically perform a command after yanking text [Vim wayland clipboard]

Tags: cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard, wayland

I want to copy contents of the recently used `"` register automatically into my system clipboard after a yank command.

The way I achieve this now is by `nnoremap <C-@> :call system("wl-copy", @")<CR>`.

`wl-copy` is a [Command-line copy/paste utilities for Wayland](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard) and it will copy the input you give it to system clipboard.

**What my mapping above achieves is**

1. take the contents of the `"` register,

   - denoted by the `@"` argument
2. and pass contents of `@"` as an argument to the system `wl-copy` function

   - shown by `:call system("wl-copy", @")`.

But it requires me to press `Ctrl + @` when I want to populate my system clipboard with contents of the `"` register.

How can I automatically execute `:call system("wl-copy", @")` after a yank command successfully finishes (I'd like to preserve `y{motion}` but not have to continuously poll to see if the `"` register changed.

Other solutions that achieve this effect are welcome.

Comment: Check the `TextYankPost` autocommand

Comment: Very similar: [Define custom commands for the * and + registers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/332/51)

Comment: @MartinTournoij yeah, however this question is very old and asked at a time, when we not had the TextYankedPost autocommand.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't mark it as a duplicate @ChristianBrabandt; maybe we should mark the other one a duplicate of this?

Comment: @MartinTournoij that (or simply point to a newer ansewr here as comment). Don't know how to mark that as a dupclicate for another stackexchange site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [TextYankPost](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#TextYankPost) autocmd to trigger the copy to system clipboard whenever text is yanked into a register.

A very simple version of that is:

```
augroup wayland_clipboard
  au!
  au TextYankPost * call system("wl-copy", @")
augroup END
```

This will trigger the operation whenever a yank into *any* register happens, which is a bit wasteful but probably not too bad... You can refine it by inspecting which register was yanked into from the `v:event` special variable.

See [`:help TextYankPost`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#TextYankPost) and [`:help v:event`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v%3Aevent) for more details.

Comment: Can you explain the need for the first `au!` in the augroup?

Comment: @brother-bilo It removes all autocmd's in that augroup. See [`:help autocmd-remove`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-remove). That's so that if you source your vimrc or this script again, it won't install repeated autocmd's with the same action. That's a very common pattern when using autocmd's. See also [`:help :augroup`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aaugroup) which mentions this exact pattern.