# Choices for pasting

Tags: vimrc, os-clipboard, shortcut

In my local PC I use `p` in Vim command mode for pasting and it works fine and the `:echo has('clipboard')` returns 1.

But, in the cluster I am working `p` in command mode, which just inserts a 0 instead of pasting and `echo has('clipboard')` returns 0.

I suppose I have to modify my `.vimrc` file.

I tried:

```
nnoremap p "0p"
```

and:

```
"*p
```

but with no result.

```
:version

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 15 2020 16:44:08)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-629
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +cscope          +folding         +menu            +netbeans_intg   -sniff           +virtualedit
+arabic          +cursorbind      -footer          +mksession       +path_extra      +startuptime     +visual
+autocmd         +cursorshape     +fork()          +modify_fname    +perl            +statusline      +visualextra
-balloon_eval    +dialog_con      +gettext         +mouse           +persistent_undo -sun_workshop    +viminfo
-browse          +diff            -hangul_input    -mouseshape      +postscript      +syntax          +vreplace
++builtin_terms  +digraphs        +iconv           +mouse_dec       +printer         +tag_binary      +wildignore
+byte_offset     -dnd             +insert_expand   +mouse_gpm       +profile         +tag_old_static  +wildmenu
+cindent         -ebcdic          +jumplist        -mouse_jsbterm   +python/dyn      -tag_any_white   +windows
-clientserver    +emacs_tags      +keymap          +mouse_netterm   -python3         -tcl             +writebackup
-clipboard       +eval            +langmap         +mouse_sgr       +quickfix        +terminfo        -X11
+cmdline_compl   +ex_extra        +libcall         -mouse_sysmouse  +reltime         +termresponse    -xfontset
+cmdline_hist    +extra_search    +linebreak       +mouse_urxvt     +rightleft       +textobjects     -xim
+cmdline_info    +farsi           +lispindent      +mouse_xterm     +ruby/dyn        +title           -xsmp
+comments        +file_in_path    +listcmds        +multi_byte      +scrollbind      -toolbar         -xterm_clipboard
+conceal         +find_in_path    +localmap        +multi_lang      +signs           +user_commands   -xterm_save
+cryptv          +float           -lua             -mzscheme        +smartindent     +vertsplit       -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=s
sp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__linux__ -D_REENT
RANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr
/lib64/perl5/CORE  -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl
-lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/COR
E -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```

I modified my `.vimrc` file as follows according to the comments:

```
set number
set shiftwidth=4
set clipboard=unnamed 
nnoremap p "*p nnoremap p <cmd>r !xclip -o -selection clipboard<CR>
```

But, now `p` does nothing. I want `p` to paste.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `:version` to your question. The `clipboard` feature is something that's compiled in - or not. My guess is your cluster has a minimal version of Vim installed.

Comment: So in your cluster, your Vim does not have acess to the system clipboard. And even if it had, it would be hard to access your system clipboard from your cluster (it may work using `ssh -X` or similar). However I suppose your actual problem is getting your system clipboard accessible from within your cluster. That is not a Vim problem however.

Comment: @Friedrich done.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Note how it says `-clipboard` and "HUGE version without GUI". I'd try and install a GUI version. On your local PC, you probably have a GUI version with `+clipboard`. On a side note: 7.4 from ten years ago? We're using Vim 9 these days.

Comment: Yes, you are right about + and - clipboard. Thanks a lot. 
The version of vim is provided in a cluster by the institution I work for.

Comment: So that's case closed? Does Vivian's answer work for you? If not, consider refining your question so we know what's still missing.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the `'clipboard'` feature is that: It synchronizes:

- The `+` register and the system clipboard
- The `*` register and the selection clipboard (On Windows there are the same)

Remark:

- When the `'clipboard'` option is set to `unnamed` the `*` is the default register to `yank` (copy) and `put` (paste)

```
:set clipboard=unnamed
```

- When the `'clipboard'` option is set to `unnamedplus` the `+` is the default register to `yank` (copy) and `put` (paste)

```
:set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

You can use an external program (e.g. `xclip`) to read the content of the clipboard and insert it into your text:

```
nnoremap p <cmd>r !xclip -o -selection clipboard<CR>
```

You could be interested by the following questions:

- [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/23502)
- [Define custom command for the `*` and `+` registers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/332/23502)

Comment: You're talking about the `'clipboard'` *option* while OP is asking about the `+clipboard` *feature*.

Comment: My intention was to describe both but my text was confused (and actually wrong). I have made a new version. I believe it is more correct.

Comment: Looks good. I doubt OP's problem can be fixed from within Vim but let's see if it helps.

Comment: Hello,
i modified my .vimrc file as follows 
set number
  2 set shiftwidth=4
  3
  4
  5 set clipboard=unnamed
  6 nnoremap p "*p
  7 nnoremap p <cmd>r !xclip -o -selection clipboard<CR>

Comment: Hello,
i modified my .vimrc file as follows 

set number
set shiftwidth=4
set clipboard=unnamed
nnoremap p "*p
nnoremap p <cmd>r !xclip -o -selection clipboard<CR>

But , now p do nothing. Thanks for the help.

@VivianDeSmedt

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but my suggestion was slightly different: `nnoremap p <cmd>r !xclip -o -selection clipboard<CR>`. What is the result of `xclip -o -selection clipboard` on the command prompt (terminal)? – 
Vivian De Smedt
yesterday

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt hello,
$ xclip -o -selection clipboard
bash: xclip: command not found

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What is the output of `xsel -ob`? If you don't have the clipboard feature in Vim you need a program to read/write the clipboard content. Typical exemple are `xclip` or `xsel`.