# Text get weird staircase indent on copy

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I copied [this file](https://gist.github.com/benawad/f3a1a2f4b731710b0886cbd6f64fe3d5) to vim and enumerated items got weird staircase pattern indent.
Why so and how can I prevent this text corruption on a copy? It seems that it happens not only with enumerated items but rather in general every time I am copying some text it gets corrupted in Vim.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy/paste new text without auto-indentation at every new line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-copy-paste-new-text-without-auto-indentation-at-every-new-line)

Comment: @HerbWolfe thank you, it's definitely helpful, but I still cannot properly paste text, if I do p or +p it just pasts cropped partial text with missing big chunk of text from the top, I do not understand why.

Comment: @YohanRoth did you try with paste set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you get this "staircase" effect when pasting is that you have settings that will cause Vim to want to auto-indent this block, but the text you paste has indentation itself.

So every time a line break goes through the paste, Vim will copy the indentation from the line above, but then your paste will introduce another set of spaces/tabs from the indentation of the original document.

Another common artifact from pasting into a document is that Vim might want to rewrap long lines, especially when the `'textwidth'` option is set.

The [`'paste'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27paste%27) option exists exactly for this use case, while `'paste'` is enable, Vim masks the behavior of a handful of options, such as `'autoindent'`, `'textwidth'` and `'formatoptions'`, among others, so that the interference with text coming from a paste is kept to a minimum. It also disables insert mode mappings and abbreviations.

Using `'paste'` can be awkward, since you first enable it with `:set paste`, then start insert mode, actually paste the text, use `<Esc>` to leave insert mode and finally use `:set nopaste` to disable paste.

Plug-ins such as [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) build on this option by creating commands (`[op`, `]op` and `yop`) which will enable `'paste'` for a single use and enter insert mode for you.

See vim-unimpaired's [help for `[op`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/4afbe5ebf32ad85341b4c02b0e1d8ca96a64c561/doc/unimpaired.txt#L109):

> A toggle has not been provided for `'paste'` because the typical use case of wrapping of a solitary insertion is inefficient:  You toggle twice, but you only paste once (YOPO).  Instead, press `[op`, `]op`, or `yop` to invoke `O`, `o`, or `0C` with `'paste'` already set.  Leaving insert mode sets `'nopaste'` automatically.

(Note: the context is that for most other options handled by vim-unimpaired, the `[o` turns it on and the `]o` turns it off...)

If you're running a Vim instance that has clipboard support, then you can also use one of the clipboard registers (`"*` or `"+`) to paste directly from the clipboard, using either `"*p` or `"+p` in Normal mode. Unfortunately, clipboard registers and ensuring they work in our system depends a lot of your system setup and it's a bit out of scope for this answer... But you should find a question that covers getting them to work in your setup (if you don't, then feel free to ask one.)